# macOS Ventura - Losing network connection after VPN disconnects

Tags: vpn, openvpn, macos-ventura

I have an OpenVPN, and when I make a connection everything looks good - both the internet and VPN connection works. But after I disconnected the VPN, I am immediately loosing the internet connection. Turning off/on wifi helps to solve the issue.
Do you know how can I solve it without restarting the wifi each time?